# How to make ChoiceField not required?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am building a form using Django which has dynamic removing of inputs in rows.

`ChoiceField` is required by default, however, when including it in in my form it causes an error.

If I remove it and submit, the form cannot be validated.

Is there a way to set the `ChoiceField` as not required?

For example, with `ModelChoiceField` :

```
ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model.objects.all(), requied=False, empty_label=None)
```

I tried to set the choices like that, but still couldn't use `required=False` :

```
#In models:
choices = (
        ('', '-') #Tried also as None, '-'
        (0, 'Yes'),
        (1, 'No'),         
    )

#In forms:
forms.ChoiceField(choices=Model.choices, label=""),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo error change requied into required:

Change

```
ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model.objects.all(), requied=False, empty_label=None)
```

change to this :

```
ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model.objects.all(), required=False, empty_label=None)`
```